# Sharepoint rest api Version number increments on Checkout rather than check in

Tags: rest, versioning

Consider a file whose current version number is 1.0.

I am checking out the file through rest api and the UIVersionLabel property of the file, is incremented to 2.0 after checkout operation. When i check the details of the same file on sharepoint site, the version is displayed as 1.0 and only after checkin, the version is updated to 2.0.

But in the case of rest api, the version is incremented to 2.0. Which is the correct property of the file object to retrieve the right version?

Comment: Is only major versions are enabled or major and minor versions are enabled in your document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIVersionLabel  is the correct property to be used.

My solution to the question above is :

When a user checks out a file, the file's version is incremented but only the user who has checked out the file can see this incremented version. Everyone else still can see the non-incremented version. Only when the user checks in, the new incremented version is displayed to all the users.

UIVersionLabel  property contains the correct version number for each user. The user is determined from the authentication token provided along with the Rest Call. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have only major versions enabled in document library.

SharePoint's default behavior is the same when you are getting the version number in REST query.

The checked in version is: 6.0

[image]

After checking out it became 7.0 version.

[image]

However, if you want to display the last checked in version of the file you can get that idea from `CheckoutUserId` property. When you query a particular item, you can check the value of `CheckoutUserId` is null or not. If it null then the item is currently checked in, if it is not then it checked out.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
i have only major versions enabled. When i checkout using rest api and check the properties of the file, the version number displayed is still the old one and not the incremented one! Any ideas as why this is so?